# userData is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

This is my first time using ReactJS and I keep getting error

> 'userData' is not defined  no-undef

even when I declare it. Here's my code:

```js
class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userData: [],
            fullName: "",
            email: "",
            uname: "",
            pass: ""
        }
    }

    onRegis = () => {
        const { fullName, email, uname, pass } = this.state 
        userData = [{fullName, email, uname, pass}]
        this.setState({
            userData
        })
        console.log("Datanya euy: ", userData)
        // console.log(email, " is ", fullName, "'s email addres with username ", uname, " and password ", pass);
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot define variable `userData` by `var`, `let` or `const`

```js
const userData = [{fullName, email, uname, pass}];
```

Comment: so, i still need to define the variable eventhough I declare them?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have to define each variable witch you are going to use. In your code, I don't see a definition of variable `userData `. :)

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language and sometimes I don't know how to explain my question... I see, I thought I don't have to define `userData` anymore because I already put it in this.state at the beginning. Thank you! :D